# Looking for manufacturer name of USB devices

Tags: usb

I am confronted with USB memory keys and Android tablets which are labelled "eyeboom".

Does anybody know the manufacturer's name of these devices? I have searched everywhere but "eyeboom" as a manufacturer of electronic devices does not seem to exist.

Comment: That's the purpose to find manufacturer? This is probably some rebranded Chinese generic manufacturer (which can be sold under 10 different names).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft includes a utility in its [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513) (WDK) called [USBView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> USBView (Universal Serial Bus Viewer, Usbview.exe) is a Windows
>   graphical user interface application that enables you to browse all
>   USB controllers and connected USB devices on your computer. USBView
>   works on all versions of Windows.

which provides a wealth of information about connected USB devices. It also decodes the vendor ID (image from [here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/335A90747734097886257070006415B9)):

[image]

Install USBView, plug in the USB devices, open USBView and see which manufacturer information is shown in the `idVendor` field.